# Why is this IAM policy statement failing to match?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have an IAM policy statement that is supposed to allow a user to open a tunnel via an EC2 Instance Connection Endpoint.

The policy statement is (with suitable redactions):

```json
{
    "Action": "ec2-instance-connect:OpenTunnel",
    "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
            "ec2-instance-connect:privateIpAddress": "<EC2_IP>"
        },
        "NumericEquals": {
            "ec2-instance-connect:remotePort": "22"
        },
        "NumericLessThanEquals": {
            "ec2-instance-connect:maxTunnelDuration": "3600"
        }
    },
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:<AWS_ACCT_NO>:instance-connect-endpoint/<EICE_ID>",
    "Sid": "EC2InstanceConnect"
}
```

When I attempt to connect via SSH through the tunnel, I get the following error:

```
awscli.customizations.ec2instanceconnect.websocket - ERROR - {"ErrorCode":"AccessDeniedException","Message":"User: arn:aws:sts::<AWS_ACCT_NO>:assumed-role/<ROLE>/<USER? is not authorized to perform: ec2-instance-connect:OpenTunnel on resource: arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:<AWS_ACCT_NO>:instance-connect-endpoint/<EICE_ID> because no identity-based policy allows the ec2-instance-connect:OpenTunnel action"}
```

When I look at the corresponding CloudTrail Event, i can confirm:

```
"requestParameters": {
    "instanceConnectEndpointId": "<EICE_ID>",
    "maxTunnelDuration": "3600",
    "remotePort": "22",
    "privateIpAddress": "EC2_IP"
}
```

I even tried the IAM Policy Simulator with the relevant role, action, resource and parameters iand it says "no match".

I can't see where I'm going wrong here. I do have a support ticket open, but thise feels like I should be able address it myself.

Any pointers?

Comment: If you temporarily suppress the policy conditions, can you connect?

Comment: Great suggestion... removing the conditions result in a match, so I'll add them one at at time and see what trips it

Comment: I think the policy simulator is a little broken when it comes to `ec2-instance-connect:OpenTunnel`, since the rendering of test resources is a little messed up and you can't get rid of the first one, which has no context attached to it

Comment: Yes, seems like it's broken. Policy simulator is not the real set of authorization tests performed by the actual services afaik so it's sensible to always check things for real.